# Im learning classes, getting a syntax error in line 13 in my code

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm learning classes and objects and how to make them interact. This is one of my practices but I keep getting a syntax error in line 13. Any help or advice is highly appreciated.

```
class teacher:
      def __init__(self, name, year, subject):
        self.name = name
        self.year = year
        self.subject = subject
    
      def assigned_student(self, student):
        if student.year == self.year and student.year == self:
          print("Hello, {name}! You will be in my class of {subject}".format(name = student.name, subject = self.subject))
        else:
          print("Sorry {name}. I will not be your teacher this year".format(name = student.name)
    
    class student:
      def __init__(self, name, year, subject):
        self.name = name
        self.year = year
        self.subject = subject
    
    teacher_one = teacher("Rodolfo", 6, "Math")
    student_one = student("Chino", 6, "Math")
    
    assigned_student(teacher_one, student_one)
```

Comment: Line 13 or line 3??

Comment: Could be an indentation error if your code is copy-pasted.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: Line 13, this is the error message:

File "<string>", line 13
    class student:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I've checked for indentation errors but can not seem to find any. Any idea where could it be?

Comment: How many opening and how many closing parentheses are in lines 1–12?

Comment: Missing `)` in the line before.

Comment: You probably also want both your classes to be at the same level of indentation, rather than defining the student class inside the teacher class.

Answer (score 0):

1. `print("Sorry {name}...")` has missing closing parentheses.
2. Dedent class student, you probably don't want inner class there.
3. `assigned_student` method should be called like `teacher_one.assigned_student(student_one)`